# Make Adobe Bridge scan folders and all sub folders

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-bridge

I would like to ask Adobe Bridge to find all pictures in folder and all sub folders. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adobe Bridge is a browsing program and it does not create a database of images. The best you can do, I think, is to see the images contained in the subfolders below the selected one:

1. Select the folder you want to review
2. Go to View on the top menu and click next to Show Items From Subfolders as shown in the image below
3. It will list all the images in all the subfolders

The caveat is that this is not a "sticky" setting and you need to make this choice every time you visit a folder. I do not see any settings in the preferences to make it stick, that is probably a good thing because some folders may contain a large number of subfolders and a large number of images. If you want a cataloged view of folders, look into another Adobe product, Ligtroom.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Adobe Bridge CC 2022 (12.0), click on the `>` at the end of the folder path:

[image]